# NDK cutils and c missing

Tags: linux, android-ndk, shared-libraries, android.mk

I am trying to build an executable with NDK. However I am getting the following error:

> Tools/android-ndk-r14b/build/core/build-binary.mk:687: Android NDK: Module ABCD depends on undefined modules: cutils c
>
> Tools/android-ndk-r14b/build/core/build-binary.mk:700: *** Android NDK: Aborting (set APP_ALLOW_MISSING_DEPS=true to allow missing dependencies)    .  Stop.

How can I fix it?

Comment: It will be quite hard to relate to your problem without more details and make file...

Comment: Please don't abuse Markdown. The blockquote character (`>`) should only be used for quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `cutils` and `c` from `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES` and `LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES`. That's always been a no-op in your build file: https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/208